# Punteros en C y funciones

Tags: c, funciones, punteros, memoria

tengo algunas dudas sobre como funcionan los punteros en c en funciones:
Supongamos que tengo `main()` y una función `copia` definida fuera de ese main (`copia(char * origen, char * destino, int tamaño)`).

Si lo que quiero es copiar cadena de caracteres, es decir que origen apunte a destino.

```
copiar(char * origen, char * destino, int tamaño){
// ¿Como puedo poner aquí para que la cadena que yo pasé como 
// parámetro en origen, se copie en la zona de memoria de destino?
}
```

Si no lo entiendo mal, `char * origen`, me darán como parámetro la dirección de memoria de origen, y por otro lado con `char * destino` me darán la dirección de memoria de destino, pero ¿Como hago que una dirección de memoria apunte a otra?

Gracias

Saludos comunidad.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow, he editado tu pregunta para dar formato de código donde corresponde y resolver errores ortográficos. Por favor, haz clic en _editar_, para ver como se hace. Te invito también a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funcionamos por aquí y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: que tiene que ver que una direccion de memoria apunte a otra??? me parece que eso no es lo que queres decir...

Answer (score 0):

#### Sobre las direcciones de memoria

Si lo que quieres es que los datos en una dirección de memoria apunten a otra, tienes que hacer un puntero a un puntero.

```c
// El dato
char dato = 'A';
// La direccion de memoria del dato
char *puntero = &dato;
// La direccion de memoria de la direccion de memoria del dato
char **puntero2 = &puntero;
```

Entonces asi es como haces que una dirección de memoria apunte a otra.

#### Sobre la funcion que presentas

Por la funcion que colocas, mas bien parece que quieres copiar la informacion **de una direccion de memoria a otra**. Esto es mas simple, solo vamos de una en una copiando los datos

```c
void copiar(char * origen, char * destino, int tamaño){
    for (int i=0; i<tamaño; i++) {
        destino[i] = origen[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: siempre cuando la memoria en destino este alocada en suficiente cantidad.. si no, vas a sobreescribir cualquier cosa...

Comment: *Si lo que quieres es que los datos en una dirección de memoria apunten a otra, tienes que hacer un puntero a un puntero...* La dirección del dato no apuntará a otra, es la dirección del puntero que apuntará a otra.. Más bien, no necesitas de un puntero doble para lograr que una dirección apunte a otra, con un puntero simple basta.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Yo lo que entedi con *una dirección de memoria apunten a otra* es que quiere la direccion de memoria del puntero. Por eso lo puse asi.